# Find energy formula

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential, hydrogen

I am struggling with this question my teacher gave me,

### Prompt

Consider the hydrogen molecule, $^2H$, where each hydrogen atom has just one proton.  The
system has rotational, vibrational, and electronic excitations.  The lowest energy states are
those  with  the  oscillator  in  its  ground  state  (and  the  electrons  in  theirs),  but  allowing  for
rotation of the nuclei. We will focus on these rotational levels (calling the sum of the rotational
and electronic energies $E_0$).

### Question

By  considering  the  radial  equation,  write  a  formula  for  the  energies  of  these  states
expressed in terms of $\ell$, the proton mass, and the separation of the nuclei, $R_0$. (Recall
$m$ is the reduced mass)
$$
-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\frac{d^2 u}{dr^2} + \left({V(r) + \frac{\hbar^2\ell(\ell + 1)}{2mr^2}} \right)u(r) = E u(r).
$$

#### My Question

To "write the energies of these states," do I solve for $u(r)$ by guessing a solution like: $$A\sin(kr)?$$

Comment: How would you even *start* solving that equation without specifying $V(r)$??

Comment: Have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_rotor#Quantum_mechanical_linear_rigid_rotor

Comment: So the energy could be written like $E_\ell = \frac{\hbar^2\ell(\ell + 1)}{2mr^2}$?

Comment: For a purely rigid *quantum rotator*, yes. See also: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/molecule/rotqm.html